# Como fazer query com count

Tags: mysql, sql, big-data

Eu tenho a tabela **Resultado** com milhares de dados, 
Tabela Resultado

```
    NOME_CASA,   NOME_OPONENTE, RESULTADO_FINAL, NOTA_FINAL.
    timeAzul     timePreto         1             2 
    timeAzul     timeBranco        2             2.10 
    timeBranco   timeAzul          3             2.20
    timeCinza    timeAzul          3             1.7  
    timeverde    timePreto         1             1.92 
    timePreto    timeRosa          2             2.05 
    timeAzul     timeBranco        1             2.08
```

Acima mostrei apenas um resumo das colunas e dados na tabela, observem que os dados podem se repetir, para entendimento melhor da pergunta dividi em 2 query que vai nos auxiliar na minha dúvida:

QUERY 1- Retorna todas as equipe da casa, que a nota final esteja entre 2 e 2.20.

```
SELECT NOME_CASA FROM Resultado where  NOTA_FINAL between 2 and 2.20
```

QUERY 2 - Retorna todas as equipe da casa, com nota final entre 2 e 2.20, e filtra os que o resultado_final foi igual a 1.

```
   SELECT NOME_CASA FROM Resultado where  NOTA_FINAL between 2 and 2.20 and RESULTADO_FINAL = 1 ;
```

Vejam que a consulta fiz na tabela inteira. Agora, eu preciso pegar todas as NOME_CASA que a aplique os dois filtros que citei para cada time especifico, ou seja retornar os nomes dos times onde jogando com nota_final 2 e 2.20, 60% das vezes ou mais termine com o resultado_final =1; Ou seja testaria essa condição para cada time, e retornaria o nome deles.

Resumindo preciso dos nomes das equipes(`NOME_CASA`) sem duplicar, que 60% das vezes terminam com o `resultado_final = 1`, quando as `NOTA_FINAL`dele estejam entre 2 e 2.20.

Usando os dados que postei como exemplo, somente o timeAzul retornaria na consulta que preciso, pois em um total de 3 jogos do timeAzul, 3 atendia a query1 e 2 deles terminaram com o resultado_final = 1. Então(2 * 100) / 3 = 66.6%¨

Como montar essa query?

Comment: Olá Clara, pelo que entendi você quer trazer as equipes que possuem um total de registros(usando os filtros da Query2) acima de 60% da quantidade de resultados da *QUERY1*, certo?

Comment: @AndréFilipe na verdade quero buscar todos as equipes(nomeCasa) que emn 60% ou mais das vezes, tiveram o resultado_final = 1, quando a nota_final deles esteja entre 2 e 2.20. Note que a query1 que usei é para toda tabela posso ter errado nisso, preciso saber de cada time. Exemplo todas as evzes que o time azul jogou e estava a nota_final entre 2 e 2.20, digamos que retorne 10 jogos, agora preciso saber quantos desses jogos o resultado_final = 1, digamos q foi 7, então temos 70%. Sendo que isso foi pra apenas um time,quero uma query que traga o nome de todos os times que estejam nessa condição.

Comment: @AndréFilipe acabei de editar o post, eu posso ter me expressada errado

Comment: Clara, fiz uma resposta de seu caso e me dê um retorno se é como esperado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lí umas dezenas de vezes sua pergunta para conseguir entender o seu problema, espero que esteja no raciocínio correto.

Utilizando a cláusula `count(*)` consegui a quantidade de registros para cada *query*, e na cláusula `HAVING` criei a lógica da porcentagem `%` da qual comentou em sua pergunta.

```
SELECT NOME_CASA AS NOME_CASA_COLUNA, 
       count(*) as qtd_query2 
FROM Resultado
       WHERE NOTA_FINAL between 2 and 2.20 and RESULTADO_FINAL = 1
GROUP BY NOME_CASA
HAVING ((qtd_query2 * 100) / 
    ( SELECT count(*) AS qtd_query1 
        FROM Resultado
        WHERE NOTA_FINAL between 2 and 2.20 AND NOME_CASA = NOME_CASA_COLUNA
     GROUP BY NOME_CASA HAVING qtd_query1 > 1)) > 60;
```

Nessa *query* apliquei a `Query2` como consulta externa e em seguida faço uma validação com a quantidade total de registros da Query2 e verifico se ela é equivalente à 
60% ou mais que a quantidade de registros retornados na `Query1`.

Comment: Exatamente, muito obrigada!!!

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudá-la!

Answer (score 5):

Veja também no [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpfv45KhHYj2tqu5BHsAwr/5).

```
SELECT nome_casa, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN resultado_final = 1 THEN 1 
                  ELSE NULL 
             END) / COUNT(*) AS percentual
FROM Resultado
WHERE nota_final BETWEEN 2.00 AND 2.20
GROUP BY nome_casa
HAVING percentual >= 0.60;
```

Answer (score 4):

Pelo o que eu entendi, você quer usar o COUNT para montar essa query query `((Query2 * 100) / QUERY2)` e obter um resultado numérico. Tente fazer dessa forma:

```
((SELECT COUNT(nome_casa) FROM resultado WHERE nota_final BETWEEN 2 AND 2.20) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(nome_casa) FROM resultado WHERE nota_final BETWEEN 2 AND 2.20 AND resultado_final = 1)
```

Comment: Juliana, eu editei o post, acho que  tinha ficado confuso. Eu preciso pegar todas as NOME_CASA que a aplique os dois filtros que citei para cada time especifico, ou seja retornar os nomes dos times onde jogando com nota_final 2 e 2.20, 60% das vezes ou mais termine com o resultado_final =1; Ou seja testaria essa condição para cada time, e retornaria o nome deles.